# Why wont useRoute variable update vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Trying to create breadcrumbs, by getting the URL full path and spliting in a Array, then, loop through that array as render some crumbs.

the issue is that `crumbs` wont get updated when a route changes, how can i make this work?

```
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const store = useThemeStore();
    const { fullPath } = useRoute();

    return {
      changeThemeStore: computed(() => store.changeTheme),
      currentTheme: store.getCurrentTheme === "dark",
      crumbs: computed(() => fullPath.substring(1, fullPath.length).split('/'))
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeTheme() {
      this.changeThemeStore();
    },
    goToRoute(crumb: string) {
      this.$router.push('/' + crumb)
    }
  },
```

Comment: why are you adding `.value` at the end?

Comment: Mixing options and compositon api is possible but not a good practice. You'll have more problems with typings, and methods aren't reachable from setup function

Comment: honestly i don't know why there's a `.value` there. intelisense must have gave me a suggestion and i added it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to not destruct the current route and use it directly, it seems that destructed object loses the reactivity :

```js
 const route = useRoute();
...
 crumbs: computed(() => route.fullPath.substring(1, route.fullPath.length).split('/'))
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe that actualy worked. I also removed `.value` at the end and it works